# Mac terminal permission denied

Tags: mac, unix, terminal

First of all i'm not sure if SO is the right place for this question, but...

I'm trying to run a unix executable file that i downloaded and when i double click it, it opens the terminal and tries to run it and it says permission denied. I went to get info on the file and all of the users are set to read and write permission.

How can i run this file?

Comment: Update your question with the results of `ls -l filename`

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add execute permission. "chmod +x filename"

Obvious question: Do you trust the file?